# C# Linq-to-Entities OrderByDescending isn't working

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6

Here is my entity called `SportTeam`:

```
public class SportTeam : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public int SportId { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    public int TotalPlays { get; set; }
    public int TotalWins { get; set; }
    public int TotalDefeats { get; set; }
    public int TotalDraws { get; set; }
    public float WinPercentage { get; set; }
    public float Score { get; set; }

    // navs
    public virtual Ladder Ladder { get; set; }
    public int? LadderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Sport Sport { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Match> HomeMatches { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Match> RivalMatches { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Match> VictorMatches { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tournament> Tournaments { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        SportTeam sportTeam = (SportTeam)obj;

        if (sportTeam.Id == Id)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return 2108858624 + Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I am trying to sort the `SportTeam` entity by score by doing this

```
List<SportTeam> sportTeams =
                dbContext.SportTeams
                         .Where(st => st.SportId == sportTeam.SportId)
                         .OrderByDescending(st => sportTeam.Score)
                         .ToList();
```

However when I add a watch over the `sportTeams` list, the list doesn't appear to be ordered by score at all. I just get an as in representation of the table.

Any hints?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are sorting on a constant value (`sportTeam.Score`) Try

```
OrderByDescending(st => st.Score)
```

instead of

```
OrderByDescending(st => sportTeam.Score)
```

Comment: stupid me..I just coincidently found that out too. I will this as correct as soon as i can